# Accessory button on annotation callout

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm trying to add an accessory button to my map annotation but I can't get it to work. I've searched for it a lot but nothing seems to work. Please help me!

Here's my code:

```
//Annotations

//Pildammsparken
CLLocationCoordinate2D pildLocation;
pildLocation.latitude = PILD_LATITUDE;
pildLocation.longitude = PILD_LONGITUDE;
//Malmöhus Slott
CLLocationCoordinate2D malmohusLocation;
malmohusLocation.latitude = MALMOHUS_LATITUDE;
malmohusLocation.longitude = MALMOHUS_LONGITUDE;

//Pildammsparken - Annotation
MapPin *annPild = [[MapPin alloc] init];
annPild.title = @"Title";
annPild.subtitle = @"Subtitle";
annPild.coordinate = pildLocation;
[mapview addAnnotation:annPild];
//Malmöhus slott - Annotation
MapPin *annMalmohus = [[MapPin alloc] init];
annMalmohus.title = @"Title";
annMalmohus.subtitle = @"Subtitle";
annMalmohus.coordinate = malmohusLocation;
[mapview addAnnotation:annMalmohus];

[mapview setShowsPointsOfInterest:NO];
```

I want a button at the end of the small annotation that will take you to a page where you can read more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your viewcontroller to be the map view's delegate and implement the following methods:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"PinAnnotationView"];
    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"PinAnnotationView"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;
    NSLog(@"user tapped annotation with title: %@", annotation.title);
}
```